# Захват глобальных переменных лямбдой

Tags: c++, lambda

Как правильно захватывать глобальные переменные в лямбде? Хочу использовать следующим образом, но выдаются предупреждения. Как их подавить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int offset = 1;
int scale = 2;


int main() {
    auto shift = [&offset, scale](int b) { return (offset + b) * scale; };
    std::vector values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::transform(values.cbegin(), values.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout}, shift);
}
```

Comment: А зачем вам вообще захватывать глобальную переменную по ссылке? Она же глобальная - она вам и так доступна, причем именно "по ссылке".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Глобальные переменные, как и статические, нет необходимости (и не разрешается) захватывать. Их можно использовать в лямбдах без захвата.

---

Если очень хочется иметь в лямбде копию переменной (например если лямбда - `mutable`, и эту копию хочется изменять), то можно использовать захват с инициализацией:
`[offset_copy = offset, scale_copy = scale](int b) /*...*/`.

Comment: хм, действительно работает без предупреждений. А захватывать можно в принципе или это баг компилятора?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, но захват по значению делает копию, что отличается от использования глобальной переменной.

Comment: @Qwertiy Дополнил.

Comment: @klinton Захватывать нельзя, но предупреждение вместо ошибки - это не баг компилятора (компиляторы с настройками по умолчанию часто намеренно компилируют код, не соответствующий стандарту, но это не тот случай), и даже не нарушение стандарта - стандарт требует, чтобы компилятор выдавал сообщение, если программа некорректна. А что это: варнинг или ошибка - не важно.

Comment: Изменять может не только лямбда, но и окружающий код ;)